# How do I get OMXPlayer to run in the background on Raspbian Jessie?

Tags: raspbian, boot, debian, omxplayer

With Wheezy, I successfully managed to follow [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX4f3BWOwAc) to run OMXPlayer during boot-up for a video splash screen. However, with the latest Jessie OS downloaded from the Raspberry Pi Foundation's website, it is no longer working.

Further inspection shows that the line `omxplayer video_file.mp4 &` will not run in a typical terminal environment, whilst `omxplayer /home/pi/video_file.mp4` does. Other methods (besides the ampersand [&]) to get the video to run in the background (i.e. using nohup) simply caused the boot sequence to get stuck and never complete.

I have also tried getting it to launch from a Python script which is launched via a background process, however this is subject to the same issues. I also attempted to use a separate terminal instance via `screen`: `screen -S splashscreen -d -m omxplayer /home/pi/video_file.mp4`, but, again, no such luck when run during startup.

Is there something that I am missing? What can I do to get this working?

Comment: od there anything in the logs? errors? warnings?

Comment: No errors or warnings - where can I find logs?

Comment: use omxplayer's '--no-keys' flag to disable key binding, so it can run in background and then the ampersand will work.  omxplayer --no-keys file.avi &